# Is the preimage of $f\colon (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1+x_2 +x_1x_2$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1+x_2 + x_1x_2$. Let $E \subset \mathbb R$ be a connected set containing $0$ and $E$ is not the singleton $0$. Is $f^{-1}(E)$ connected?

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811840/is-the-preimage-of-fx-x-1-x-2-dots-x-n-connected/2811878#2811878). I tried to follow one of the answers to construct a path to $0$ by $t \mapsto t(x_1, x_2),$ but this does not seem to work since there is a sum of different order of $t$.

Comment: Hint: $f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 + 1) (x_2 + 1) - 1$ will relate this question to the one you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Consider the connected set $E=[-1/2,+\infty)$ which contains $0$ in its interior and it is not a singleton. Then $S:=f^{-1}([-1/2,+\infty))$ is the set of points $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R ^2$ such that 
$$x_1+x_2 +x_1x_2\geq -1/2.$$
Is $S$ connected? Note that $P:=(0,0)\in S$ and $(-2,-2)\in S$. Let $\gamma$ be a continuous path  from $P$ to $Q$ then, by continuity, $\gamma$ will intersect the line $x_1=-1$ at some point $R$. Does $R$ belong to $S$?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. I meant to ask when $E$ contains $0$ in its interior. Will this change the result?

Comment: @iris2017 It's fine. You can replace $-1/2$ with any real number $>-1$. Can you see why?

Comment: I see. Thanks so much. Don't know why someone downvoted your answer.

Comment: @iris2017 Glad to be helpful.